# Facebook Messenger Bot sharing structured message with postback button

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm in the middle of reviewing Facebook messenger platform and can't find any info on particular subject. I want bot user to share a structured message with his contacts, which would bring contact back to a bot chat caring a context.

Sharing of structured message works well:

1. bot response with message containing template with 'Share Button'
2. click on button opens native share menu
3. user selects contacts to share message with
4. message is sent to contacts
5. each contact receives message as original

All that is as explained in the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/share-button

The next part of a puzzle is 'Postback Button' that can be added to a structured message template in the same way as 'Share Button' (explained here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/postback-button). Tap on 'Postback Button' sends metadata to a webhook. All fine with that as well...

Let's say I have a bot that does a songs search. User types part of lyrics and bot offers list of songs matching those. Each song is listed by bot as structured message which has 'Share Button' and 'Postback Button' called 'Like'. Idea is that such message is shared by user to his contacts. Idea behind 'Like' (Postback Button) is to be clicked by contact receiving a message. Each click on 'Like' should bring user to bot chat and execute postback. Logic behind postack is tracking of user's contacts who liked particular song.

All that works until point when contacted user clicks 'Like'. Click opens a bot chat (first time users see welcome info), but no postback is executed. The same is if I use 'URL Button' (with Messenger Extensions).

Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Thx

Here's example of message with postback button I want to use:

```
var messageData = {
  recipient: {
    id: recipientId
  },
  message: {
    attachment: {
      type: "template",
      payload: {
        template_type: "generic",
        elements: [{
          title: "Shake it off",
          subtitle: "Lorem ipsum....",
          buttons: [{
            type: "web_url",
            title: "Watch video",
            url: "http...",
          }, {
            type: "postback",
            title: "Like",
            payload: "id=xyz",
          }, {
            type: "element_share",
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share the json config for the postback button which you are sending?

Comment: @kinshukkar I have added message with postback button above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messenger platform got updated and new feature providing exactly what I needed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: How did you manage to get it working? I have the same problem - but sharing the structure with the ref params link instead of the postback button doesn't work well

Comment: It simply worked for me using http://m.me/mybot?ref=myparam url. @Elwhis what desn't work for you exactly?

Comment: @Andrej There is no option as fallback url for the postback button (which there is for the normal button) and when I use normal button with this url the conversation continues in new window, which isn't good

Comment: @Elwhis I'm still not clear about your use case, maybe you could give short explanation... What I had was sharing of a message with ref link, so it was expected to have conversation to continue in new window as user is coming from different conversation than one with the bot.